# Application of transformations of lognormal distributed random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, application

I'm answering questions from a book and I have to do a simple transformation Y=g(X) of a lognormal distribution:

$X \sim \mathcal{LN}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$ with $Y=ln(X)$

Then $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$

I am looking for good practical applications of when such a transformation is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Log transformations are sometimes helpful in statistical analyses of how long it takes people to react to an event.

For example, in [Effects of category diversity on learning, memory, and generalization](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2FBF03195318.pdf) a single analysis involved several dependent variables (p. 295).  The MANOVA test for significant predictors assumed that the dependent variables were normally distributed.

In this study, the raw reaction times for each participant were not normally distributed.  Reaction times were skewed, so most responses for each participant were fairly fast, but a few were much slower.

Also, for individual participants, response time variance depended on the mean.  Some participants were generally faster on most responses than other participants, who were slower.  For an individual participant, if their mean reaction time was low (= fast), their reaction time variance also tended to be low, and vice versa for participants with large (= slow) mean reaction times and variance of their reaction times.

In this study, log-transformed reaction times were reasonably consistent with the assumptions made by the statistical tools.  This made it possible to test hypotheses about the nature of cognitive processes and mental representations, which cannot be observed directly.